# Loading multiple images and applying Principal Component Analysis

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning

I have about 2000 images of faces that I need to perform Principal Component Analysis (PCA) on. Then I discard the two largest eigenvalues and plot the graph of the remaining eigenvalues sorted in decreasing order. The images are all 19 by 19 pixels each.

As an attempt to see if I can get it right I tried just taking the PCA on 1 image in Matlab in which I just do the usual stuff do load the image. At first it didn't work well but then I was told to simply take the imgradient of the image before using the Princomp function on Matlab so essentially I do this:

```
a = imread('face1.pmg');

b = imgradient(a);

[COEFF,SCORE,latent] = princomp(b);
```

This worked just dandy, but I have many many images so doing this one by one would not be that fun. Thus I tried to write a for loop where I load the images from my directory and read in each images file name and hit it with the imgradient then pass that along to the princomp function. But it seems that it only does this for the last image.

My thoughts were to index each image so that its stored in an array or matrix but I looking online I was not able to find anything that worked. This is what I have thus far, its runs just fine but like I said it doesn't seem to store all my images.

```
filePattern = 'C:\Users\Morgan Weiss\Documents\MATLAB\STA5635_HW12\faces\*.pgm';
fileList = dir(filePattern); % Will not contain any directories, only .pgm files.
for k = 1:length(fileList)
    thisFileName = fileList(k).name;
    thisImage(k) = imread(thisFileName);
    % Get the gradient of this image.
    A = imgradient(thisImage);
    % Principle Component Analysis
    [COEFF,SCORE,latent] = princomp(A);
end
```

If anyone could help me figure this out or has any suggestions at all I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to store the latent values for each iteration.  Something like

```
...
latents = zeros(19*19, length(fileList)); % store each image latent as a column
for k = 1:length(fileList)
    ...
    [COEFF,SCORE,latent] = princomp(A);
    latents(:,k) = latent;
end
```

You can modify it as you see fit.  You can sort `latent` before storing it in `latents`, etc.